# Proving a number has its n-root using intermediate value theorem (most general case)

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, alternative-proof

I want to prove using the intermediate value theorem the existence of the n-root of a number $a$ and I'm thinking to do this using several steps:

---

### $n$ even

**If $a>1$**

> Since the function $f(x)=x^n-a$ is continuous and $f(0)=-a<0$ and $f(a)=a^n-a=a(a^{n-1}-1)>0$, then by the intermediate value theorem we have the statement proved.

**If $0<a<1$**

> Since the function $f(x)=x^n-a$ is continuous and $f(0)=-a<0$ and $f(\frac{1}{a})=\frac{1}{a^n}-a=a(\frac{1}{a^{n+1}}-1)>0$, then by the intermediate value theorem we have the statement proved.

---

### $n$ odd

**If either $a>1$** or $0<a<1$

> The same when $n$ is even

**If $a<0$**

> I don't know

---

## Questions

1. Am I right so far?
2. Is there an easy way without so many steps to solve this question using Intermediate value theorem?
3. How can we prove the last part?

---

Comment: Yes you are right so far and most textbooks also do it the same way. For $a<0$ put $a=-b$ so that $b>0$. Then $n$'th root $b^{1/n}$ exists by previous argument and one can see that $(-b^{1/n})^{n}=(-1)^{n}b=a$ ($n$ is odd). Therefore $n$' th root of $a$ is $-b^{1/n}=-(-a)^{1/n}$.

Comment: You also need to show that for positive $a$ there is a unique positive $n$'th root and similarly for $a<0$ if $n$ is odd.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thank you. How can we prove the uniqueness?

Comment: The function $f$ is strictly monotone on $[0,\infty)$ and hence takes the value $0$ only once.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh of course, thank you again!